# Enforce minimum separation between ones in binary array

Tags: python, pandas

I have time series with generated binary signals, like this below:

```
date    value
1/4/1987    0
1/5/1987    1
1/6/1987    1
1/7/1987    0
1/9/1987    0
1/10/1987   1
1/12/1987   1
2/1/1987    1
2/2/1987    1
2/3/1987    1
2/4/1987    1
2/6/1987    1
2/7/1987    1
2/9/1987    0
2/10/1987   0
2/11/1987   0
2/12/1987   1
3/2/1987    0
3/3/1987    1
3/4/1987    1
3/6/1987    1
3/8/1987    1
3/9/1987    1
3/11/1987   1
3/12/1987   0
```

I'm trying to figure out the way to reduce their number, so that there will be a fixed gap of 10 observations between 1's.

```
date    new_value
1/4/1987    0
1/5/1987    1
1/6/1987    0
1/7/1987    0
1/9/1987    0
1/10/1987   0
1/12/1987   0
2/1/1987    0
2/2/1987    0
2/3/1987    0
2/4/1987    0
2/6/1987    0
2/7/1987    1
2/9/1987    0
2/10/198    0
2/11/198    0
2/12/198    0
3/2/1987    0
3/3/1987    0
3/4/1987    0
3/6/1987    0
3/8/1987    0
3/9/1987    0
3/11/1987   1
3/12/1987   0
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it can be quite tricky to come up with a vectorised approach to do this. For these cases `numba` can be a good option if we still want a performant approach. Here's how you could do it using its efficient @njit compilation mode:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def spacing_between_1(a, k):
    x = np.zeros(len(a), np.int8)
    first_one = np.argmax(a)
    x[first_one] = 1
    c=0
    for i in range(first_one+1, len(x)):
        if a[i] == 1 and c >= k:
            x[i] = 1
            c=0
            continue
        c +=1
    return x
```

---

For the shared example, we'd get:

```
a = df.value.to_numpy()
df['new_value'] = spacing_between_1(a, 10)

print(df)

           value  new_value
date                       
1/4/1987       0          0
1/5/1987       1          1
1/6/1987       1          0
1/7/1987       0          0
1/9/1987       0          0
1/10/1987      1          0
1/12/1987      1          0
2/1/1987       1          0
2/2/1987       1          0
2/3/1987       1          0
2/4/1987       1          0
2/6/1987       1          0
2/7/1987       1          1
2/9/1987       0          0
2/10/1987      0          0
2/11/1987      0          0
2/12/1987      1          0
3/2/1987       0          0
3/3/1987       1          0
3/4/1987       1          0
3/6/1987       1          0
3/8/1987       1          0
3/9/1987       1          0
3/11/1987      1          1
3/12/1987      0          0
```

Comment: Appreciate your help. I've never used numba but it looks like a powerful lib to enhance performance and certainly a great solution for problems like above. Have to dive into and familiarize. Many thanks again!